# C# Dice Times each number is rolled

Tags: c#

I've created a Dice program which rolls a dice dependant on how many times the user wishes to roll. The problem I'm having is being able to calculate how many times each number appears.

Example. Roll Twice - Number is 5. 
                      Number is 4.

I want to be able to count that a 4 and a 5 has being rolled and display it back to the user.

My Code so far

```
using System;

namespace Dice
{
    class Dice
    {
        private Random randy;               
        int total;

        public static void Main()
        {
            Dice myDice = new Dice();       
            myDice.randy = new Random();    
            Console.Clear();                

            myDice.manyThrow();
            myDice.throwDice();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        //*******************************************************
        public void throwDice()
        {
            double count = 0;
            while(count != total)
            {
                count++;
                Console.WriteLine("Throw No " + count + " is " + oneThrow());    
            }
        }

        //*******************************************************
        public int oneThrow()
        {
            return randy.Next(6) + 1; // pick a number from 1 to 6 and return this
        }

        public int manyThrow()
        {
                Console.Write("How many times do you want to roll\t");
                total = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                return total;
        }

        public void countEm()
        {
            // This is where I intend to place the code
        }    
    }
}
```

I've being trying to solve this for hours.

Comment: Shouldn't be to hard, using an array as big as the times it is going to be thrown and insert a dice value every throw.

Comment: So what exactly do you have trouble with? Save the rolled numbers and generate statistics.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dice rolling in C# console application giving incorrect totals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187010/dice-rolling-in-c-sharp-console-application-giving-incorrect-totals)

Comment: Solution to your (potentially homework) post is already available on the site. Check out linked/related posts. If it is not homework please specify how cool code should look like (LINQ, Reactive extenstions, Observable pattern, DI and whatever else you want to be used).

Comment: There are dozens of correct answers on this page, pick the one that helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Add an array to count roll results:

```
using System;

namespace Dice
{
    class Dice
    {
        private Random randy;
        int total;
        int [] rolls = new int[7];

        public static void Main()
        {
            Dice myDice = new Dice();
            myDice.randy = new Random();
            Console.Clear();

            myDice.manyThrow();
            myDice.throwDice();
            myDice.countEm();
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        //*******************************************************
        public void throwDice()
        {
            double count = 0;
            while (count != total)
            {

                count++;
                Console.WriteLine("Throw No " + count + " is " + oneThrow());

            }
        }

        //*******************************************************
        public int oneThrow()
        {
            var result = randy.Next(6) + 1;        // pick a number from 1 to 6 and return this
            this.rolls[result]++;
            return result;

        }
        public int manyThrow()
        {

            Console.Write("How many times do you want to roll\t");
            total = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            return total;

        }
        public void countEm()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i<7; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} rolled {1} times", i, rolls[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Elegantly done. I have a mental problem that refuses to allow me to allocate an extra element on that array, even though it sure does make for pretty looping :-)

Answer (score 1):

Modify the countEM like this:

```
public void countEm(int numberOfThrows)
{
      List<int> Throws = new List<int>(); //Create list, where value of throws will be stored.
      for(int i = 0; i < numberOfThrows) //Loop as many times as are given by parameter.
      {
          Throws.Add(OneThrow()); //Add return value of throw to the list.
      }
      //Show values in Throws list.
      foreach(var diceValue in Throws)
      {
           Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Value of throw: {0}", diceValue ));
      }
}
```

coutEM should be called with the number of times you want to throw like:

```
countEM(5);
```

Above represents 5 throws. The result for example could be filled with:

> 1, 4, 6, 3, 4

Comment: @JoeStead oops haha, typing from phone. Thanks for letting me know:)

Comment: @JoeStead Galaxy Note 3, with keyboard attached.

Comment: This may violate the comments policy (not sure), but shout out to another Note 3 user. Absolutely crazy about mine, can't imagine going to something different.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw Haha, I think it is nice, but not without flashing a stock rom on it, like a tweaker should:)

Comment: I had stock and then CM on my Gnex, and it was nice, but I wanted to keep the S-Pen functionality. Action Launcher Pro keeps most of the Samsung crap out of my way :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`static int[] counts = new int[6];`

And in `oneThrow()`:

```
int result = randy.Next(6);
counts[result]++;
return result + 1;
```

Then in `countEm()`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < counts.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i + 1, counts[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep an array of the possible outcomes count.

```
class Dice
{
    private Random randy;               
    private int total;
    private static const int NUM_SIDES = 6;
    private int[] counts;

    public Dice()
    {
        randy = new Random();
        counts = new int[ NUM_SIDES ];
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Dice myDice = new Dice();
        Console.Clear();                

        int throws = myDice.manyThrow(); // need to save the number of throws
        myDice.throwDice( throws );
        countEm();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public void throwDice( int throws )
    {
        double count = 0;
        while(count != throws)
        {
            count++;
            int result = oneThrow();
            counts[ result - 1 ]++; // NOTE: result-1 because arrays are 0-based.
            Console.WriteLine("Throw No " + count + " is " + oneThrow());    
        }
    }

    // ...

    public void countEm()
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < counts.Count; ++i )
            Console.WriteLine( (i+1) + " thrown " + counts[i] + " times." );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to keep track of the count of each number rolled, then you add to your class an array of integers to store the count of each number rolled. The number of the dice roll could be the index into the array.

If you need to keep track of the order of the numbers rolled. Your class could could use a linked list or other ordered list to keep track of the numbers.

This sort of sounds like a homework assignment, so I'll leave the implementation details to the reader :)